# UTTypeCopyPreferredTagWithClass: getting all tags

Tags: objective-c, mime-types

In ObjC, `UTTypeCopyPreferredTagWithClass` returns the first tag associated with a certain UT type. How can I obtain all tags, instead? I mean, `jpg` AND `jpeg` instead of just `jpeg`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`UTTypeCopyDeclaration` retrieves those infos.